# A copy of a metric space

Tags: general-topology

Question:

Suppose that a metric space $(X,d)$ contains exactly four points, $X = \{ x_1 ,x_2,x_3, x_4\}$. Is it true that one can find four points $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4 $ in some Eucledian space $ \Bbb{R^n} $ such that for any $i,j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$:

$$dist(p_i,p_j) = d(x_i,x_j)$$

Attempt:

A previous problem asked for three points in $X$ and $p_i$ in $\Bbb{R^2}$ That was straight forward but when I try to extend it to four points, there is no obvious solution. I suspect there is a method for finding one if I move to $\Bbb{R^3}$ but I'm not confidant about that. Any hints?

Comment: You need the intersection of 3 spheres around p1,p2,p3 to have at lest one point in common to choose p4.  Tw spheres inter sect at a sphere of one lower diminsion.  And two at two lower dimesions.  So N can be equal to 3.  sphere around p1 and p2 intersect in circle.  That circle intersects the sphere around p3 at two points choice on of those to be p4.  You must go into 3 dimensins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not every metric space can be embedded isometrically in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Take the four-point space $X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, c\}$, with distance function $d(x_i, x_j) = 2$, $d(x_i, c) = 1$. This is a metric space, as could be checked axiomatically, or by viewing it as a subspace of the graph where there is an edge from each $x_i$ to $c$.

Suppose $X$ embeds isometrically into $\mathbb{R}^n$. Take the plane in which $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$ live: they form an equilateral triangle with side length 2 sitting in this plane. Since $c$ must be equidistant from each, it must lie somewhere on the line through the centre of the triangle, perpendicular to the plane. In particular, it does not lie on any edge of the triangle. Hence we have a nondegenerate triangle $\{x_i, x_j, c\}$ with side lengths $(1, 1, 2)$, a contradiction.

Comment: I understand your argument but I don't see what the contradiction is. The triangle $\{ x_i, x_j, c \}$ is in a plane that intersects the previous plane at a 45 degree angle and it satisfies the triangle inequality.

Comment: Any "triangle" with side lengths $(1, 1, 2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be degenerate, in the sense that its three vertices are colinear. But we already know the triangle is not degenerate.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Let x1,x2,x3 be 1 apart and x4 1/2 from the others.
Check for the triangle inequality which would fail were
1/4 used.  Perhaps if R^3 were curved an isometric
embedding would be possible.